# Ipod classic was corrupted, so erased everything off it using disk utility

Tags: itunes, hard-drive, ipod, ipod-classic

So my ipod classic was corrupted, and i read somewhere that you could use disk utility to erase everything off it (i read somewhere that this was nessesary). My computer now does not register it as an ipod, but rather as untitled on my home screen. I am afraid that i have deleted everything off my ipod, including the actual ipod software! when i connext the ipod to my laptop itunes opens but the ipod does not appear on the screen. What to do please help !!

Answer (score 5):

You can follow the troubleshooting options [here](http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/five_rs/classic/#), and if it still does not work, please let us know.

It's also sounding like there's a possibility of a failed HDD in that iPod. Using [diagnostic](http://www.wikihow.com/Access-and-Run-Diagnostic-Tests-on-an-iPod-Video) mode, can you give us the details on the "Memory" SMART test?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Mac, be sure you formatted the iPod's HDD as "Extended, Journaled". For Windows, use Fat32. It's named "untitled" as that is the default name used when reformatting any drive. You can rename it manually by clicking the drive icon in Finder. In iTunes, look for the iPod in the series of icons upper left, or try clicking the ellipsis (. . .) button. If you still cannot see the iPod, please comment again.